# How to correctly read from already opened std::ifstream using a buffer

Tags: c++, caching, ifstream

### Background

I implement a JSON parser and offer an `operator>>` function to parse from an `std::ifstream`. To speed up reading, I copy 16 KB into a buffer and let my parser read from the buffer. A small benchmark showed that this is faster than directly working with `std::ifstream::get` or `std::ifstream::read`.

### Current (buggy?) implementation

When I successfully read a JSON value, I want to "put back" all unneccessary bytes from the buffer to the stream so a subsequent call of `operator>>` with the same `std::istream` continues parsing right where the first call ended. I currently implement this "putting back" like this:

```
is.clear();
is.seekg(start_position + static_cast<std::streamoff>(processed_chars));
is.clear();
```

Thereby, `is` is the input file stream, `start_position` is the initial value of `is.tellg()`, and `processed_chars` the number of characters read by the parser.

This works with GCC and Clang with OSX and Linux, but MSVC 2015 and MSVC 2017 fail to bring the input stream into the desired state.

### My questions

1. Apparently, I am doing something wrong here. The different compilers should not behave so differently. The `clear()` calls are already the result of trial&error to make the code run with GCC/Clang.
2. What would be the correct way to (a) read from an already opened `std::ifstream` using a cache and (b) be able to resume parsing after the last processed character (instead after the last cached character)?
3. Is there a better way to quickly read from an already opened `std::ifstream`? As I mentioned above, removing the cache makes the parser slower.

(Apologies for the naive question and the horrible implementation! I did not find an answer on this that coped with an already open `std::ifstream` or that could "put back" already cached characters.)

Comment: hmmm do you actually need it to compile under MSVC ? you can create windows executables with GCC/Clang even from a linux/Mac machine, right ?

Comment: You can create a custom buffered file stream by writing a custom `::std::streambuf` implementation.

Comment: @niceman In the end, I ship only a header that should compile everywhere, see https://github.com/nlohmann/json

Comment: @VTT Can I use this custom buffer with a passed `std::ifstream` object? And how would "putting back" characters from the buffer to the stream look like?

Comment: Typically you would pass your `streambuf` instance pointer to `istream` when creating it and there is not need to use `ifstream` at all. stream will handle "putting back" and other operations as long as you supply corresponding overloads in you `streambuf` implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you open a file stream in text mode, this is not valid:

```
is.seekg(start_position + static_cast<std::streamoff>(processed_chars));
```

...because according to the standard, `seekg` / `tellg` are not directly related to the number of processed chars (this is actually OS-dependent).

Here are possible options for you (cannot give more details with what you gave in your question):

- use [`putback`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/putback) to put back the character you read  but did not use;
- use `tellg` to get the correct position.

Something like this maybe:

```
// is is the istream
auto tg = is.tellg();
is.read(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
 // process...
is.seekg(tg); // valid
is.ignore(processed_chars);
```